# Lock Computer after X minutes, non user editable

Tags: linux-mint, screensaver, udev, lock

Case: I have younger siblings who have a linux computer. They are not allowed to access this computer without parental approval and entry of a password. Their solution is to disable my locking mechanism by means of changing the "Lock After" time.

I am the superuser: Is there something, like perhaps a UDEV rule or a daemon that looks for user input, and if not present it starts xscreensaver? Like, wait 5 minutes then lock? That way they can not bypass the system by simply changing a GUI box.

The operating system is Linux Mint, a Debian distro.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GNOME Nanny](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Nanny)?

Otherwise, you could run something like [`sinac`](http://lists.suckless.org/dwm/att-4685/sinac.c) in the background. If `~/.xprofile` or `~/.xinitrc` are honoured by your environment, just put something like follows there. This is assuming they aren't smart enough to kill¹ the subshell running this too.

```
while :; do sinac -w "$TIMEOUT"; "$LOCKER"; done
```

`$TIMEOUT` could be something like 900 for a fifteen minute limit, and `$LOCKER` can be `slock`, `xscreensaver`, or whatnot.

¹: Could run as a separate user so that they don't have permission to `SIGKILL` it too.